# How do I convert a string "nine" to 9?

Tags: php

I know I can do that using switch(), but still I wanted to know if there's any PHP function for that.

Comment: How far do you want to take it? Beyond 10?

Comment: `function convertTo9($s) { return $s == "nine" ? 9 : null; }` :)

Comment: People, I wanted to know if there's any function for doing so. I need it till 7 only. I knew how to get it working, but you guys have provided some interesting examples. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: *related* : [Converting words to numbers in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some devious way of abusing `strtotime()` for this... But let's better not try to find out. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From one to ten:

```
$numbers = array("zero" => 0, "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4, 
                 "five" => 5, "six" => 6,  "seven" => 7, "eight" => 8, 
                 "nine" => 9, "ten" => 10);

echo $numbers["nine"]; // 9
```

Beyond that, it gets trickier (except if you want to type out a very large list, of course.)

Comment: @Felix yeah. This was done with converting it back in mind, but good point. Editing.

Comment: And you excluded zero because...?

Comment: @Eric *insert complicated mathematico-philosophical explanation here* I forgot.