# Is there any php function to convert textual numbers to numbers? For example: convert("nine") outputs 9

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting words to numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php)

I need a function to convert textual numbers to numbers.
For example: convert("nine") outputs 9

I know I could write a function like for example if ($number == "one") { $number = 1; } etc...
but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php

Comment: For every number or can you restrict the set of possible numbers (e.g. 0-10)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch statement.

Comment: How many `case` s that would be? Let's see: 1,2,3,4,5,6... 100,...1000, ... 128434520346.... oh I'm too tired to count any further...

Comment: @Felix Kling: Given a 32-bit system, just over 2 billion.

Comment: @BoltClock: But I have a 64-bit system :-P *You* can continue counting.... ;) :D

Comment: Oh that's very different than 0-9 which is what I thought you wanted.  You are looking for a natural language parser then.  I haven't done that before.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup table like this:

```
$numbers = array(
    'zero' => 0,
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
    'six' => 6,
    'seven' => 7,
    'eight' => 8,
    'nine' => 9
);

$digit = strtolower($digit);

if (isset($numbers[$digit])) {
    $digit = $numbers[$digit];
}
```

Note I use strtolower just in case.  Of course, this solution would be impractical for anything over a couple dozen.  Beyond that, you'll need some sort of parser.