# PHP Function that can convert an alphabetically spelled number to numeric?

Tags: php, string, numeric

Let's say I have strings such as:

```
$ten = 'ten';
$eleven = 'eleven';
$three = 'three';
```

etc.

Is there a pre-built function which will convert these into numeric strings based on the English language?

i.e.

```
return process_to_number($ten); // returns 10 as a numeric value
return process_to_number($eleven); // returns 11 as numeric
return process_to_number($three); // returns... you guessed it, 3!
```

I guess I could write this manually too (since I only have to process between one and sixteen) but I thought I'd check if there was something like this already.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php

Comment: You can count all the consonants in the word? I have tested it, it works quite wel for the first 3, so I assume it works for the rest too.

Comment: Why do you have strings instead of numbers in the first place? Just wondering..

Comment: @Nanne There are two consonants in 'ten', so that won't work will it.

Comment: @Robinv.G. this probably has to do with processing text input received from humans ;)

Comment: There is no built-in function in PHP for this, so you'd better juist build a `switch()` statement. This is (given the constraints of only having to capture 1-16) the easiest solution. However, I really wonder what you're trying to do. Is this about user input? What if they enter '1' instead of 'one'? What about typos ('tow' vs 'two')? Can't you just use a dropdown? Anyhow see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php) question.

Comment: ... consonants? 

@Robinv.G. good question. I could have it the other way around too, it doesn't matter to me actually. I could use a function that converts 10 to "ten" spelled out.

Comment: I'm using two different CSS grid systems in one, and they get deployed to multiple sites. Some of them have the skeleton (class="seven columns alpha") while others have the old 960 (class="grid_7 alpha") and I need to include both classes. I guess with only up to 16 columns I may as well build a manual switch function, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pre-built one, but there is [this](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/) rather nice piece of code that you could try to reverse engineer? It's a very complicated area, and one algorithm won't work for all languages (Japanese is base 10,000 and not 1,000 - like English - AFAIK).

Comment: Nice code example, but he's looking for words to numbers, not numbers to words!

Comment: Or how about for($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; $i++) if(convert_number_to_words($i) === $ten) return true;

;)