# Get the numeric items from string

Tags: php, c

Hello I have `WR4G9T5HTJ3w2RFG1` string which contains alphabatic and numeric letters so I want get the numbers from this string like `123459`. So please help me to solve this.

Comment: `c` or `php`? Make a choice.

Comment: Any solution attempts ? Have you tried anything ?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str); // 495321`. For a C-based solution, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13399677/1438393).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

PHP

```
echo getNumbersFromString('WR4G9T5HTJ3w2RFG1');
function getNumbersFromString ($str) {
        preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
        return implode("",$matches[0]);
    }
```

i have put some part of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php/11243531#11243531)

my intension was not to copy the answer i just used and modify the answer as per the question requirement.

Comment: This is a rephrase of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11243531/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str= 'salom34554dfgfd';
        $array[]='salom34554dfgfd';
        for($i=1; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
            if(is_numeric($array[0][$i])){
                echo $array[0][$i];
            }
        }
```

i think u mean this

Answer (score 0):

result code  :

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $your_string);
```

or

```
$result = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $your_string);
```