# How Do I Take Out Only Numbers From A PHP String?

Tags: php, string, numbers

Suppose, I have this string:

```
$string = "Hello! 123 How Are You? 456";
```

I want to set variable `$int` to `$int = 123456;`

How do I do it?

Example 2:

```
$string = "12,456";
```

Required:

```
$num = 12456;
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$int = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: It's *not* a duplicate of that question, which is about getting *all/any (groups of)* numbers.

Comment: Here is the solution-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Correct variant will be:

```
$string = "Hello! 123 How Are You? 456";
$int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string), 10);
```

Comment: Now you check your code for string "hello 0123"... :)

Comment: @ArifHussain yes, it works for 0123 and provides proper decimal 123, as expected

Comment: @Lashane , so in that case Shankar's code is also correct, which you commented on.

Comment: This code will malform large numbers, for example `abc12345678901234556782312312323123123131232`

Comment: @mike php by nature cannot work with such big numbers, you need special library for this

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method to select only digit present in your text

```
function returnDecimal($text) {
    $tmp = "";  
    for($text as $key => $val) {
      if($val >= 0 && $val <= 9){
         $tmp .= $val
      }
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Inefficient and slow.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression `!\d!`

```
<?php
$string = "Hello! 123 How Are You? 456";
preg_match_all('!\d!', $string, $matches);
echo (int)implode('',$matches[0]);
```

[image]

Comment: A `0` before a number is not required.

Comment: Shankar, I think what Lashane is getting at is that (int) will cast that as octal if it's prefaced by a 0.  Or am I completely off?

Comment: @Helpful you're right, you cannot just use (int) to convert string to number in php

Comment: @Lashane, You are not getting it, the regex grabs the numbers from the string , and casting it to `int` is not going to making it as octal.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes, I've mistaken with javascript where you 0 prefixed numbers will be supposed as octal

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below:

```
$array = [];

preg_match_all('/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?+/', $string, $array);
```

Where $string is the entered string and $array is where each number(not digit!,including also negative values!) is loaded and available for different more operations.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $string = "ABC100";
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
    $number = $matches[0][0];
    echo $number;
?>
```

**Output:
100**

Comment: This code-only answer provides no new value to this page or Stack Overflow.  Please only answer when you have something unique and valuable to add to the page.  Worse, it only displays the first of all matches.