# How do I get the last part of an url string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need extract item id from url's like these (number after last slash)

```
http://codecanyon.net/item/test item/12219820
                                   //^^^^^^^^
http://codecanyon.net/item/another item/75219586
                                      //^^^^^^^^
http://codecanyon.net/item/item contain number v1.2/74419586
                                                  //^^^^^^^^
```

Some items has digits in name.
How i can extract just id at end of links with regular expression in php?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 i tested this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php  but this not works for link 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just take the last part of the url (string) with [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php))

```
echo basename($url);
```