# How to get certain part of a string value in php?

Tags: php, string

I get one value like "`13and45`" and would like to know if there is a way so I can store these values separately like

```
$string="13and45";    

$value1=13;    

$value2=45;
```

Do you guys know how I can manipulate the string in order to get something like what I have above?

Comment: Try `strpos()` maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words ?

Comment: There're a lot of ways to get what you need.

Comment: Are you trying to get numeric values inside a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP split string into integer element and string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get numbers from string with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php)

Comment: yes im trying to get numeric numbers Ali Farhoudi

Answer (score 3):

[PHP - Explode () function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

This will return an array with the two values.

Example:

```
$array = explode ("and", $string);
```

Returned array with strings:

```
$array[0] = 13
$array[1] = 45
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `intval(substr($string, 0, 2)` to get the first integer and `intval(substr($string, 5, 2)` for the second. intval will get the integer value from a string, and substr will get the portion of the string given by ($string, index, length).