# Get int value from string 'word'

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting words to numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php)

I've been searching around for a bit, but haven't come across anything as of yet. Is it possible to do the following:

```
$columns = 'four';
$columns_int = PHP_FUNCTION($columns);

return $columns_int;

// returns int(4)
```

I believe I was playing around with Ruby and saw something like this, but thought this was also available in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve-o Does that really help then? ;)