# converting-words-to-numbers-in-php II

Tags: php, numbers, words

There is a great function here [Converting words to numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php) from El Yobo.
But I have the problem that the string must begin with a written number.
How can convert e.g. "iPhone has two hundred and thirty thousand, seven hundred and eighty-three apps" ?

The explained function:

```
function wordsToNumber($data) {
// Replace all number words with an equivalent numeric value
$data = strtr(
    $data,
    array(
        'zero'      => '0',
        'a'         => '1',
        'one'       => '1',
        'two'       => '2',
        'three'     => '3',
        'four'      => '4',
        'five'      => '5',
        'six'       => '6',
        'seven'     => '7',
        'eight'     => '8',
        'nine'      => '9',
        'ten'       => '10',
        'eleven'    => '11',
        'twelve'    => '12',
        'thirteen'  => '13',
        'fourteen'  => '14',
        'fifteen'   => '15',
        'sixteen'   => '16',
        'seventeen' => '17',
        'eighteen'  => '18',
        'nineteen'  => '19',
        'twenty'    => '20',
        'thirty'    => '30',
        'forty'     => '40',
        'fourty'    => '40', // common misspelling
        'fifty'     => '50',
        'sixty'     => '60',
        'seventy'   => '70',
        'eighty'    => '80',
        'ninety'    => '90',
        'hundred'   => '100',
        'thousand'  => '1000',
        'million'   => '1000000',
        'billion'   => '1000000000',
        'and'       => '',
    )
);

// Coerce all tokens to numbers
$parts = array_map(
    function ($val) {
        return floatval($val);
    },
    preg_split('/[\s-]+/', $data)
);

$stack = new SplStack; // Current work stack
$sum   = 0; // Running total
$last  = null;

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if (!$stack->isEmpty()) {
        // We're part way through a phrase
        if ($stack->top() > $part) {
            // Decreasing step, e.g. from hundreds to ones
            if ($last >= 1000) {
                // If we drop from more than 1000 then we've finished the phrase
                $sum += $stack->pop();
                // This is the first element of a new phrase
                $stack->push($part);
            } else {
                // Drop down from less than 1000, just addition
                // e.g. "seventy one" -> "70 1" -> "70 + 1"
                $stack->push($stack->pop() + $part);
            }
        } else {
            // Increasing step, e.g ones to hundreds
            $stack->push($stack->pop() * $part);
        }
    } else {
        // This is the first element of a new phrase
        $stack->push($part);
    }

    // Store the last processed part
    $last = $part;
}

return $sum + $stack->pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well .. i have to admit.. this was interesting to me on a personal level !!! anyway ... here is the code... you can test it here : http://www.eyerollweb.com/str2digits/

and here is the code itself:

```
<?php

//The Test string
$str = "two hundred thousand six hundred and two";

$numbers = array(
    'zero' => 0,
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
    'six' => 6,
    'seven' => 7,
    'eight' => 8,
    'nine' => 9,
    'ten' => 10,
    'eleven' => 11,
    'twelve' => 12,
    'thirteen' => 13,
    'fourteen' => 14,
    'fifteen' => 15,
    'sixteen' => 16,
    'seventeen' => 17,
    'eighteen' => 18,
    'nineteen' => 19,
    'twenty' => 20,
    'thirty' => 30,
    'forty' => 40,
    'fourty' => 40, // common misspelling
    'fifty' => 50,
    'sixty' => 60,
    'seventy' => 70,
    'eighty' => 80,
    'ninety' => 90,
    'hundred' => 100,
    'thousand' => 1000,
    'million' => 1000000,
    'billion' => 1000000000);

//first we remove all unwanted characters... and keep the text
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", $str);

//now we explode them word by word... and loop through them
$words = explode(" ", $str);

//i devide each thousands in groups then add them at the end
//For example 2,640,234 "two million six hundred and fourty thousand two hundred and thirty four"
//is defined into 2,000,000 + 640,000 + 234

//the $total will be the variable were we will add up to
$total = 1;

//flag to force the next operation to be an addition
$force_addition = false;

//hold the last digit we added/multiplied
$last_digit = null;

//the final_sum will be the array that will hold every portion "2000000,640000,234" which we will sum at the end to get the result
$final_sum = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {

    //if its not an and or a valid digit we skip this turn
    if (!isset($numbers[$word]) && $word != "and") {
        continue;
    }

    //all small letter to ease the comparaison
    $word = strtolower($word);

    //if it's an and .. and this is the first digit in the group we set the total = 0 
    //and force the next operation to be an addition
    if ($word == "and") {
        if ($last_digit === null) {
            $total = 0;
        }
        $force_addition = true;
    } else {
        //if its a digit and the force addition flag is on we sum
        if ($force_addition) {
            $total += $numbers[$word];
            $force_addition = false;
        } else {
            //if the last digit is bigger than the current digit we sum else we multiply
            //example twenty one => 20+1,  twenty hundred 20 * 100
            if ($last_digit !== null && $last_digit > $numbers[$word]) {
                $total += $numbers[$word];
            } else {
                $total *= $numbers[$word];
            }
        }
        $last_digit = $numbers[$word];

        //finally we distinguish a group by the word thousand, million, billion  >= 1000 ! 
        //we add the current total to the $final_sum array clear it and clear all other flags...
        if ($numbers[$word] >= 1000) {
            $final_sum[] = $total;
            $last_digit = null;
            $force_addition = false;
            $total = 1;
        }
    }



}

// there is your final answer !
$final_sum[] = $total;
print "Final Answer: " . array_sum($final_sum) . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: I can even edit the code for it to detect multiple numbers "set of numbers" in the same string ... like for example:
"this is sentence where i can say one and then after a while say another two hundred to get some awesome results" and the returned value would be 1, 200 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "iPhone has two hundred and thirty thousand, seven hundred and eighty-three apps";
$words = explode(' ', preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", ' ', $input)); //replace non-alpha characters like ',' with ' '
$res_arr = array();

foreach( $input_arr as $word ) {
    if( in_array($word, $number_words) ) { //$number_words being the large array given in your code
        $res_arr[] = $word;
    }
}
$clean_input = implode(' ', $res_arr);
//should look like: two hundred and thirty thousand seven hundred and eighty-three
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$val = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $val_entered = str_replace(',','',$_POST['nmbr']);
    $num_list = explode('.',$val_entered);
    $full_val = convert_num($num_list[0]);$cnxn = '';
    if($num_list[0]!=0){$cnxn = ' and ';}

    $dec_val = convert_num($num_list[1]);
    $val=' Value entered  is '.$val_entered.' =  Rupees '.$full_val.$cnxn.' cents '.$dec_val;

}
?>
<form name="cnvt" id="cnvt" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="nmbr" name="nmbr" value="0" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
<?php print  $val ?>

<?php
function convert_num($nmbr)
{
    $numword = 'Zero';
    if($nmbr>0)
    {
    $abacus = setto_abacus($nmbr);
    //print '<pre>';print_r($abacus);print '</pre>';
    $numword = read_abacus($abacus);
    }

    return $numword;

}
function setto_abacus($nmbr)
{
    $abacus = array(1000000=>0,1000=>0,100=>0,1=>0);
    $val = $nmbr; //2,500,605
    foreach(array_keys($abacus)as $key)
    {
        $abacus[$key] = (int)($val/$key);
        $val = $val %$key;
    }
    return $abacus;
}
function read_abacus($abacus)
{
    $position_name = array(100=>'Hundred',1000=>'Thousand',1000000=>'Million');
    $numvals = array(0=>'Zero',1=>'One', 2=>'Two',3=>'Three',4=>'Four',5=>'Five',6=>'Six',7=>'Seven',8=>'Eight',9=>'Nine',
    10=>'Ten',11=>'Eleven', 12=>'Twelve',13=>'Thirteen',14=>'Fourteen',15=>'Fifteen',16=>'Sixteen',17=>'Seventeen',18=>'Eighteen',19=>'Nineteen',20=>'twenty',30=>'Thirty',40=>'Forty',50=>'Fifty',60=>'Sixty',70=>'Seventy',80=>'Eighty',90=>'Ninety');
    $num_words = ""; $cnxn = '';
    foreach($abacus as $key=>$val)
    {
        $cnxn = ''; if($key==1 && $num_words !=''){$cnxn='and';}
        if($val>0)
        {
            if($val>=100)
            {   $rfnum = (int)($val/100);
                $num_words.= $numvals[$rfnum].' '.$position_name[100].' ';
                $rfnum = $val % 100;
            }
            else
            {
                $rfnum = $val;
            }
            if($rfnum>0)
            {   
                $num_words.= get_twodigit_inwords($rfnum, $cnxn);
            }
            $num_words.= ' '.$position_name[$key].' ';

        }

    }
    return $num_words;
}
function get_twodigit_inwords($rfnum, $cnxn)
{
    $numvals = array(1=>'One', 2=>'Two',3=>'Three',4=>'Four',5=>'Five',6=>'Six',7=>'Seven',8=>'Eight',9=>'Nine',
    10=>'Ten',11=>'Eleven', 12=>'Twelve',13=>'Thirteen',14=>'Fourteen',15=>'Fifteen',16=>'Sixteen',17=>'Seventeen',18=>'Eighteen',19=>'Nineteen',20=>'Twenty',30=>'Thirty',40=>'Forty',50=>'Fifty',60=>'Sixty',70=>'Seventy',80=>'Eighty',90=>'Ninety');
    $tens_words = '';$unit_words = '';

    if($rfnum>0)
    {   
        if(array_key_exists($rfnum,$numvals))
        {
            $tens_words= $numvals[$rfnum].' ';
        }
        else 
        {
            $tens_words = $numvals[(int)($rfnum /10)*10];
            $unit_words = $numvals[$rfnum %10];
        }
    }
    $twodigit_name = $cnxn.' '.$tens_words.' '.$unit_words;
    return $twodigit_name;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string=$_POST['num'];
$array1=array("one"=>1,"two"=>2,"three"=>3,"four"=>4,"five"=>5,"six"=>6,"seven"=>7,"eight"=>8,"nine"=>9,"ten"=>10,"eleven"=>11,"twelve"=>12,"thirteen"=>13,"fourteen"=>14,"fifteen"=>15,"sixteen"=>16,"seventeen"=>17,"eighteen"=>18,"ninteen"=>19,"twenty"=>20,"thirty"=>30,"fourty"=>40,"fifty"=>50,"sixty"=>60,"seventy"=>70,"eighty"=>80,"ninty"=>90);

$array2=array("hundred"=>100,"thousand"=>1000,"lakh"=>100000,"crore"=>10000000);
echo "<br>";
$number=explode(" ",$string);
echo "<br>";
$count=count($number);
$new=0;
$final=0;
foreach($number as $word)
{
    $lastTwo=$lastOne;
    foreach($array1 as $keyCN=>$valueCN)
    {   

        if($keyCN==$word)
        {
            $new=$valueCN;
            $lastOne=$valueCN;
        }
     }

    foreach($array2 as $key=>$value)
    {
         if($key==$word)
         {

            $new2=$new*$value;
            $num+=$new2;
            $lastOne=0;
            $lastTwo=0;
        }
    }   
}
$final=$num+$lastOne+$lastTwo;

echo "final is $final<br>";
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="num" value=""></br>
<input type="submit" value="Convert string to number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well something like this should

```
$numbers = array('0' => "zero",
    '1' => "one", '2' => "two", '3' => "three", '4' => "four", '5' => "five", '6' => "six", '7' => "seven", '8' => "eight", '9' => "nine", '10' => "ten", '11' => "eleven", '12' => "twelve", '13' => "thirteen", '14' => "fourteen", '15' => "fifteen", '16' => "sixteen", '17' => "seventeen", '18' => "eighteen", '19' => "nineteen", '20' => "twenty", '21' => "twenty one", '22' => "twenty two", '23' => "twenty three", '24' => "twenty four", '25' => "twenty five", '26' => "twenty six", '27' => "twenty seven", '28' => "twenty eight", '29' => "twenty nine", '30' => "thirty", '31' => "thirty one", '32' => "thirty two", '33' => "thirty three", '34' => "thirty four", '35' => "thirty five", '36' => "thirty six", '37' => "thirty seven", '38' => "thirty eight", '39' => "thirty nine", '40' => "fourty", '41' => "fourty one", '42' => "fourty two", '43' => "fourty three", '44' => "fourty four", '45' => "fourty five", '46' => "fourty six", '47' => "fourty seven", '48' => "fourty eight", '49' => "fourty nine", '50' => "fifty", '51' => "fifty one", '52' => "fifty two", '53' => "fifty three", '54' => "fifty four", '55' => "fifty five", '56' => "fifty six", '57' => "fifty seven", '58' => "fifty eight", '59' => "fifty nine", '60' => "sixty", '61' => "sixty one", '62' => "sixty two", '63' => "sixty three", '64' => "sixty four", '65' => "sixty five", '66' => "sixty six", '67' => "sixty seven", '68' => "sixty eight", '69' => "sixty nine", '70' => "seventy", '71' => "seventy one", '72' => "seventy two", '73' => "seventy three", '74' => "seventy four", '75' => "seventy five", '76' => "seventy six", '77' => "seventy seven", '78' => "seventy eight", '79' => "seventy nine", '80' => "eighty", '81' => "eighty one", '82' => "eighty two", '83' => "eighty three", '84' => "eighty four", '85' => "eighty five", '86' => "eighty six", '87' => "eighty seven", '88' => "eighty eight", '89' => "eighty nine", '90' => "ninety", '91' => "ninety one", '92' => "ninety two", '93' => "ninety three", '94' => "ninety four", '95' => "ninety five", '96' => "ninety six", '97' => "ninety seven", '98' => "ninety eight", '99' => "ninety nine", '100' => 'hundred', '1000' => 'thousand', '1000000' => 'million');

$words = explode(" ", $string);

$sw = 0;
$words = array_merge($words);




for ($nindex = 0; $nindex < count($words); $nindex++) {

    $numword = $words[$nindex];
    $preservenumword = $numword;


    if ($numword == "one hundred") {
        $numword = "hundred";
        $words[$nindex] = $numword;
    }
    if ($numword == "one thousand") {
        $numword = "thousand";
        $words[$nindex] = $numword;
    }
    if ($numword == "one million") {
        $numword = "million";
        $words[$nindex] = $numword;
    }


    $numwordarray = array_search(strtolower($numword), $numbers);

    if ($numwordarray === false || $numwordarray == 0 || $numwordarray == "") {
        unset($words[$nindex]);
    }
}

$finalNumber = 0;

for ($nindex = 0; $nindex < count($words); $nindex++) {


    $number = array_search(strtolower($words[$nindex]), $numbers);
    if ($number === false || $number == 0 || $number == "")
        continue;

    $cur = strtolower($words[$nindex]);
    if ($nindex + 1 >= count($words))
        $next = '';
    else
        $next = strtolower($words[$nindex + 1]);
    $coupleword = $cur . " " . $next;
    $couplenumber = array_search($coupleword, $numbers);

    if ($couplenumber != false && $couplenumber != 0 && $couplenumber != "") {
        if (strtolower($words[$nindex + 2]) == "hundred") {
            $finalNumber = $finalNumber + ($couplenumber * 100);

            $nindex+=2;
        } elseif (strtolower($words[$nindex + 2]) == "thousand") {

            $finalNumber = ($finalNumber + $couplenumber) * 1000;

            $nindex+=2;
        } else {
            $finalNumber = $finalNumber + $couplenumber;

            $nindex++;
        }

        continue;
    }


    if (strtolower($words[$nindex]) != "thousand" && strtolower($words[$nindex + 1]) == "hundred") {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber + ($number * 100);
        $nindex++;

        continue;
    } else if (strtolower($words[$nindex + 1]) == "thousand" && strtolower($words[$nindex]) != "hundred") {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber + ($number * 1000);
        $nindex++;

        continue;
    } else if (strtolower($words[$nindex]) == "thousand") {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber * 1000;

        continue;
    } else if (strtolower($words[$nindex]) == "hundred") {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber * 100;

        continue;
    } else if (strtolower($words[$nindex]) == "million") {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber * 1000000;

        continue;
    } else {
        $finalNumber = $finalNumber + $number;
    }
}

echo $finalNumber;
```